# Internet Explorer opening files with the wrong program

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Before I start - I am using Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 9.

I have uploaded some files to my employers content management system and these files were created by software called WriteOnline. The file extensions are .wdoc and .wbrx

When I go to download the files in Internet Explorer I get different errors for each type of file -

.wbrx files open as XML within the browser window and .wdoc files come up only with the option of opening with Microsoft Word.

I have checked my default program settings within Windows 7 and both of these file extensions are assigned to WriteOnline by default.

Does anyone know of a fix that would make both of these file types open automatically with the correct software? As many users will be downloading and opening the files it is important that the files are associated with the correct software without the user needing to change any settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try to set the 'mime-types' for these within the Content Management System. That will almost certainly require some configuration of either the CMS or the web server.

A web site uses mime-types to indicate how a file should be displayed. For example, a web server might indicate that files with a .txt extension should be displayed as if they were HTML or it might indicate they should be displayed as plain text.

The mime-types you need are:

.wdoc   application/vnd.crick.document

.wbrx   application/vnd.crick.writeonline.grid

Internet Explorer does act a bit differently from other web browsers, it looks at the data and tries to guess how it should be displayed. So it can be more troublesome than other browsers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, now looking at the CMS and server configurations to see if we can change the mime-type for these files.